# My bootstrap 4 dropdown doesn't work and I'm not sure how to resolve it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm very new to HTML and have been struggling to get my dropdown to work for a few hours now. I've searched many posts facing similar issues but I still can't find and resolve the issue. I'm unsure if the issue is caused by my scripts as well

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="logo">Logo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Action</a>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Thanks in advance!

I tried replacing `data-toggle="dropdown"` with `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` but it didn't work since I'm using bootstrap 4, copied and pasted the codes directly from bootstrap and it still failed

Comment: It's because your jQuery script isn't loading correctly. Don't use the googleapis link. Use this one `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.slim.js"></script>` That's pulling directly from the [jQuery CDN](https://releases.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The CDN isn't working for your jQuery. Bootstrap needs this to run. You get a clue for this in your console, there should be an error saying that it needed jQuery. So you can:

Replace this

https://ajax.googleleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js

With this

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bootstrap jQuery

use this code snippet for done

#### HTML Code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```